# The Qt Tray application closes by itself after performing any action in the menu

Tags: qt, c++11

I'm new in QT and I ran into a problem.

I decided to try writing a small application using Qt and QSystemTrayIcon. To start, I decided to reproduce the example from the official site of Qt.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html?

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMenu *trayIconMenu;
    QAction *launchAction;
    QAction *quitAction;
    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon;

public slots:
    void changeEvent(QEvent*);
    void trayIconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason);
    void trayActionExecute();
    void setTrayIconActions();
    void showTrayIcon();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

This is my source code file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setTrayIconActions();
    this->showTrayIcon();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showTrayIcon() {
    trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    QIcon trayImage(":/images/trayIcon.png");
    trayIcon->setIcon(trayImage);
    trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);

    connect(trayIcon, 
         SLOT(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),
         this, 
         SLOT(trayIconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

    trayIcon->show();
}

void MainWindow::trayActionExecute() {
    QMessageBox::information(this, "TrayIcon", "Info text");
}

void MainWindow::trayIconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason 
            reason) {

    switch (reason) {
        case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
        case QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick:
            this->trayActionExecute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::showMsg() {
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Tray message", "Hello world!");
}

void MainWindow::setTrayIconActions() {
    launchAction = new QAction("Launch", this);
    quitAction = new QAction("Exit", this);

    connect (launchAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(showMsg()));
    connect (quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    // Setting system tray's icon menu
    trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
    trayIconMenu -> addAction (launchAction);
    trayIconMenu -> addAction (quitAction);
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event) {
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
    if (event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange) {
        if (isMinimized()) {
            this->hide();
        }
    }
 }
```

When I perform any action in the context menu, the application simply closes. 
I thought that the point was to override the method QCloseEvent and that would fix the situation. So, i reimplent it:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    #ifdef Q_OS_OSX
    if (!event->spontaneous() || !isVisible()) {
        return;
    }
    #endif
    if (trayIcon->isVisible()) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Systray"),
                             tr("The program will keep running in the "
                                "system tray"));
        hide();
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

What can be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete verifiable example - that is, something that we can compile and run to reproduce the error. You omitted both the `start()` and `trayActionExecute()` methods, which are likely the source of the problem. Also please improve the formatting of your code through proper indentation, which would make it a lot more readable.

Comment: I apologize for the quality. I added a post via the phone and did not immediately see the terrible design. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for improving your post. Some remaining issues: `showMsg` is not declared in the header, the `closeEvent` references an unknown class `SafeEyeTimer`, and the `MainWindow.ui` file is missing (although it isn't related to your problem, you could simply remove it to get a smaller MCVE). But I can reproduce it now :)

Comment: Oh yeah, Thanks. I add this Class from another application. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be reproduced by minimizing the main window, which hides it as per your `changeEvent()` implementation, and subsequently clicking "Launch" in the system tray icon menu. The message box is displayed, and afterwards the application simply closes.

This is caused by a "feature" of QT called `QuitOnLastWindowClosed` which is enabled by default. If it is enabled, the application quits when the last *non-hidden* window is closed - in your example, this is the message box spawned by the "Launch" command (which counts as a window)!

You can solve the issue by calling `QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);` at some point after creating the `QApplication`, e.g. in the `main.cpp` which likely sets up your application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

On a side note, your `connect()` syntax in `showTrayIcon()` is wrong: It should spell `SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason))` instead of `SLOT(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason))`.

But I would highly recommend to use the **new** signal/slot syntax (https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) instead:

```
connect(trayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::activated, this, &MainWindow::trayIconActivated);
```

This has the advantage of showing you any mistakes (like unknown signals/slots or incompatible parameters) at compile-time instead of runtime.